# Dropdown Label Floating Behaviour

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

I've implemented a custom dropdown widget in my Flutter project, but I'm encountering an issue with the display of the dropdown label when the widget is used.

Here's the code snippet for my custom dropdown widget:

```
 class CustomDropdownCl extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomDropdownCl({
    required this.items,
    required this.hint,
    required this.isRequired,
    this.onChanged,
    required this.textEditingController, // Yeni eklendi
    super.key,
  });

  final List<String> items;
  final String hint;
  final bool isRequired;
  final ValueChanged<String?>? onChanged;
  final TextEditingController textEditingController; // Yeni eklendi

  @override
  State<CustomDropdownCl> createState() => _CustomDropdownClState();
}

class _CustomDropdownClState extends State<CustomDropdownCl> {
  final focusNode = FocusNode();
  String? _selectedItem;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedItem = widget.textEditingController.text.isEmpty
        ? null
        : widget.textEditingController.text;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 60,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
        color: AppColors.RegisterPageTextFieldColor,
      ),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
          color: AppColors.RegisterPageTextFieldColor,
        ),
        child: ListenableBuilder(
          listenable: focusNode,
          builder: (_, __) {
            return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton2<String>(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                value: _selectedItem,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: AppColors.black,
                ),
                hint: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: widget.hint,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.darkGray,
                    ),
                    children: [
                      if (widget.isRequired)
                        const TextSpan(
                          text: ' * ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.darkMagenta,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                isExpanded: true,
                items:
                    widget.items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: value,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.darkGray,
                          fontSize: 13,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedItem = newValue;
                    widget.textEditingController.text = newValue ?? '';
                  });

                  widget.onChanged?.call(newValue);
                },
                dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    color: AppColors.RegisterPageTextFieldColor,
                  ),
                  offset: const Offset(0, -2.3),
                ),
                menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                ),
                buttonStyleData: ButtonStyleData(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 2),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    color: const Color(0xFFf6f7fa),
                    border: focusNode.hasFocus
                        ? Border.all(color: const Color(0xFFa7a7a8), width: 2)
                        : null,
                  ),
                ),
                iconStyleData: const IconStyleData(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                    color: AppColors.darkMagenta,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 25,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I want the dropdown label to behave similarly to a TextField when focused, i.e., I want the label to float above the dropdown when it's focused.

I've tried using DropdownButtonFormField2 instead of DropdownButton2, but it messes up my styles, and all my custom styling goes into trash.

Is there a way to achieve the floatingLabelBehavior.auto effect without using any TextField? I've checked the Flutter documentation and source code, but I couldn't find a suitable solution.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "Maybe you need a text field with search functionality. When you search, you would like to have floating suggestions. Am I correct?"

Comment: @AbuSayed no. The dropdown works as expected. I want the label to float on top the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `labelText` or `label` to the `InputDecoration` should achieve what you're asking, but you will need to use `DropdownButtonFormField2`

```
DropdownButtonFormField2(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Floating label'
  ),
  ...
```